# How to import CDN correctly, what's wrong with my code with including CSS and jQuery CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cdn

I think I import my CSS and jQuery correctly but the results shown wasn't what I am looking for.

```
<!-- This snippet uses Font Awesome 5 Free as a dependency. You can download it at fontawesome.io! -->
<link ref="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link ref="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">


<style>
//all the css from the template, stackoverflow says my question is full of codes so I remove it
</style>

<body>
  <section class="pricing py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Free Tier -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Free</h5>
              <h6 class="card-price text-center">$0<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
              <hr>
              <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Single User</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>5GB Storage</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Public Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Community Access</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Unlimited Private Projects</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Dedicated Phone Support</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Free Subdomain</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Monthly Status Reports</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I get the template from: [template](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/pricing-table/)

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StartBootstrap/rgp3qdye/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=rgp3qdye)

Can anyone points out where is the problem in my code, would appreciate it.

The results should look like this
[image: results]

but I am getting this
[image: fail result]

Comment: *" results shown wasn't what I am looking for"*. How do we know what you expect if you don't explain the problem in more detail? Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: i'll update my question

Comment: it looks simple but I still not sure where's the problem

Comment: You only included the base bootstrap css, but not the additional css included with the template demo. Look at the CSS tab in the template demo

Comment: I included the css as well but I can't post stackoverflow said I am posting too much coding then words

Comment: OK. Well it appears to be working in the jsfiddle link you provided

Comment: Can you copy my code and add in CSS and check whether does it works?

Comment: seem to be missing several closing `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem, just change the "ref" to "rel" and you are good to go.
Everything was correct, just because your external stylesheet was not able to load because of "ref". To load any external css file use "rel" instead of "ref". I have attached working piece of code just for your reference. I hope, it solves your problem.

```html
<!-- This snippet uses Font Awesome 5 Free as a dependency. You can download it at fontawesome.io! -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">


<style>
section.pricing {
  background: #9CECFB;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #65C7F7, #9CECFB);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #65C7F7, #9CECFB);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.pricing .card {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.pricing hr {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.pricing .card-title {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pricing .card-price {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.pricing .card-price .period {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.pricing ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.pricing .text-muted {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.pricing .btn {
  font-size: 80%;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* Hover Effects on Card */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pricing .card:hover {
    margin-top: -.25rem;
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .pricing .card:hover .btn {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

</style>

<body>
  <!-- This snippet uses Font Awesome 5 Free as a dependency. You can download it at fontawesome.io! -->

<section class="pricing py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Free Tier -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Free</h5>
              <h6 class="card-price text-center">$0<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
              <hr>
              <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Single User</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>5GB Storage</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Public Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Community Access</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Unlimited Private Projects</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Dedicated Phone Support</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Free Subdomain</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Monthly Status Reports</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Plus Tier -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Plus</h5>
              <h6 class="card-price text-center">$9<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
              <hr>
              <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span><strong>5 Users</strong></li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>50GB Storage</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Public Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Community Access</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Private Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Dedicated Phone Support</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Free Subdomain</li>
                <li class="text-muted"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>Monthly Status Reports</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pro Tier -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Pro</h5>
              <h6 class="card-price text-center">$49<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
              <hr>
              <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span><strong>Unlimited Users</strong></li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>150GB Storage</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Public Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Community Access</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Unlimited Private Projects</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Dedicated Phone Support</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span><strong>Unlimited</strong> Free Subdomains</li>
                <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>Monthly Status Reports</li>
              </ul>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Button</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```